# При создании APK в Eclipse: An internal error occurred during: "Running Android Lint"

Tags: android, eclipse

После импорта проекта (из старой версии эклипса в новую, только что установленную) уже исправил все ошибки, но теперь при создании APK (не подписанного) появляется ошибка:

> An internal error occurred during: "Running Android Lint".
>   com/android/ide/common/repository/ResourceVisibilityLookup

При этом apk-файл создаётся без ошибок (при завершении создания), но не устанавливается (пишет "Приложение не установлено" (предыдущую версию приложения с телефона удалил))

В чём же может быть причина этой ошибки, и почему может быть ошибка "Приложение не установлено", если в эклипсе у меня ни одной ошибки, ни одного Warning? (вроде пишут, что так бывает, если не удалил до конца предыдущее приложение, что-то там про подписи, но у меня даже root-деинсталлятор приложений старое не находит, и имени моего пакета вообще не осталось на устройстве)

Answer (score 1):

В моём случае проблема решилась благодаря другому способу создания apk: ПКМ по проекту -> Export -> Android -> Export Android Aplication (1-е). При этом создал keystore и ключ, и *подписанное* apk.

Правда, *есть один нюанс*: раньше и при таком способе вылетала ошибка, но после множества попыток шаманить в эклипсе, видимо, что-то сработало, и она перестала появляться, и apk стал рабочим, хотя ошибка по-прежнему есть при старом способе создания apk (Android Tools -> Export Unsigned Application Package) (и apk создаётся нерабочий)